# How can I convert pdf to office using node js library?

Tags: node.js, doc

## convert pdf to office

how can I solve pdf to office or pdf to word. using node js
or use node js library.

```
exports.convertToDoc = catchAsyncError(async (req, res, next) => {
  const filePath = req.file.path;
  const fileName = req.file.originalname;
  const outputDir = path.join(__dirname, "..", "public/uploads");
  con

  try {
    const outputFilePath = path.join(outputDir, outputFileName);

    const command = `unoconv -f docx -o ${outputDir} ${filePath}`;
    exec(command, async (error) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error(`Error occurred during the conversion process: ${error}`);
        return next(
          new ErrorHandler(
            "Error occurred during the conversion process.",
            500,
          ),
        );
      }

      res.download(outputFilePath, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(`Error occurred during the download process: ${err}`);
          next(
            new ErrorHandler(
              "Error occurred during the download process.",
              404,
            ),
          );
        }

        fs.unlinkSync(filePath);
        fs.unlinkSync(outputFilePath);
      });
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(`Error occurred during the conversion process: ${err}`);
    fs.unlinkSync(filePath);

    next(
      new ErrorHandler("Error occurred during the conversion process.", 500),
    );
  }
```

## Error

"Error occurred during the conversion process."

and what is the reason for this problem.

Comment: What happens if you run that same `unoconv -f docx...` command directly from a command-line shell? Please [edit] your question to tell us.